# terminal - combining find with xargs - find on the right side

Tags: shell, terminal, find, xargs

There is a file in plain text named **keywords.txt**,

For every **WORD** in **keywords.txt**, I want to find all the filename in current directory containing that **WORD**

```
cat keywords.txt | xargs find . -name
```

Error in **Mac**:

```
find: xxx: unknown primary or operator
```

Error in **Ubuntu**:

```
find: paths must precede expression: xxx
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec|time] [path...] [expression]
```

Question:

1. It would be great if you can tell me why the error occurs, How to fix it?
2. I want to pass the pattern to find so that I can find every filename containing **WORD**, how to do that?

   ```
   cat keywords.txt | xargs find . -name {*WORD*}
   ```

I searched google, most of the use cases:

**find** on left and **xargs** on right side, not the answer I expect.

Comment: Are you looking for the keywords in the filename or in the contents of the files?

Comment: keywords in the filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs since `xargs` adds more than one word to the end of the given command, resulting in a `find` invocation that may look like

```
find . -name string1 string2 string3 etc.
```

---

The following short shell script will find all files (regardless of type) that contains any of the strings given on its command line anywhere in their filenames:

```
#!/bin/sh

# construct options for 'find' that matches filenames using multiple
# -o -name "*string*"
for string do
    set -- "$@" -o -name "*$string*"
    shift
done

# there's a -o too many at the start of $@ now, remove it
shift

# add e.g. -type f to only look for regular files
find . '(' "$@" ')'
```

You may call this from `xargs`:

```
xargs -n 100 ./script.sh <keywords.txt
```

Since the script calls `find` with an expanded command line, I have restricted the number of allowed strings to call the script with to 100 to be on the safe side.

Note that this will split strings in `keywords.txt` that contain spaces.

Comment: Thanks, the script works. I wonder if there is easier command line solution without script

Comment: @zpoint `find . | grep -F -f keywords.txt` but that will likely give you more hits than you're asking for.  Also, it would fail for filenames containing newlines, and there's no way to match against specific parts of the pathnames.